# Unable to fetch number of selected Columns or Rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, datagridview

I have the following piece of code:

```
public double[] ExtractGridData(DataGridView grid)
    {
        numCells = grid.SelectedCells.Count;
        numberOfRows = grid.SelectedRows.Count;
        numberOfColumns = grid.SelectedColumns.Count;

        double[] cellsData = new double[numCells];

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in grid.SelectedCells)
            {
                if (cell.Value != null)
                    cellsData[cell.RowIndex] = Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(numberOfRows.ToString());
        return cellsData;
    }
```

I even tried using the following code:

```
Int32 selectedRowCount = grid.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
```

I only get the number of total cells, nut not the number or selected rows or columns. What might the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not getting [`SelectedRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) populated, you may not have the correct SelectionMode set (been there, done that);

> The SelectionMode property must be set to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect for the SelectedRows property to be populated with selected rows.

If you need column and row selection, not just *entire* rows or columns, you're better off using [`SelectedCells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx) which is always populated whichever SelectionMode is set.

EDIT: If you need the number of selected rows and columns, this may help (untested since I don't have a WIndows box handy)

```
int xsize = 0, ysize = 0;
var b = a.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().ToList();
if (b.Any())
{
    ysize = b.Max(x => x.RowIndex) - b.Min(x => x.RowIndex) + 1;
    xsize = b.Max(x => x.ColumnIndex) - b.Min(x => x.ColumnIndex) + 1;
}
```

Note that if you select a single cell at (1,1) and another cell at (7,7), you'll get size 7x7, even if not all cells in the range are selected.

Comment: `grid.SelectionMode` can be set using any value in [the DataGridViewSelectionMode enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86.aspx), but if you're happy with the selectionmode you already have and it's not one of the above, check my note on `SelectedCells`.

Comment: `SelectedCells` will give the entire number of cells. But is there a way to get only the number of selected number of rows and columns?

Comment: @VR17 See my update. Not tested, but should be what you're looking for.